# Cannot use object of type as array VS Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

So I'm working on this project, and I'm at the point of the pagination system. Whenever a page is called, it goes the following way:

The index page searches a page, according to the `$_GET` variable:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $tpl->parsePage($_GET['page']);
}
    else
{
    $tpl->parsePage('index');
}
```

Then the pages' name goes trough the `parsePage` function in my `tpl` class:

```
public function parsePage($pagename)
    {
        $pageid = $this->getPageIdByName($pagename);
        $page = $this->shorts(new Page($pageid));
        return $page;
    }
```

It gets the pages' ID by using a function, and then creates a new page. In the page class, the pages' content is fetched from my database:

```
public function __construct($pageid)
    {
        $pageid = $pageid['id'];
        $query = DB::$conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
        $query->bindParam(':id', $pageid, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $pageInfo = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $this->pageid = $pageInfo['id'];
        $this->title = $pageInfo['title'];
        $this->authors = $pageInfo['authors'];
        $this->contents = $pageInfo['contents'];
        $this->publish_time = $pageInfo['publish_time'];
        $this->edit_time = $pageInfo['edit_time'];
        $this->edits = $pageInfo['edits'];
        $this->editor = $pageInfo['editor'];
        $this->hidden = $pageInfo['hidden'];
        $this->parent = $pageInfo['parent'];
        $this->category = $pageInfo['category'];
    }
```

then the `$this->contents` data goes through a function which replaces all parameters with their assigned values:

```
private function shorts($content)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $this->parameter = array_merge($this->parameter, $this->user);
    }
    $this->parameter = array_merge($this->parameter, $this->language, $this->system);
    return $this->output = str_replace(array_keys($this->parameter), array_values($this->parameter), $content->contents); // Line 34

}
```

And this is where it goes wrong.. When I use this way (with `$content->contents`) the output is the following:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.tpl.php on line 34
```

First thing that popped into my mind: `$content['contents']`, but then the output is the following:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type C_Red\Template\Page as array in C:\xampp2\htdocs\application\classes\class.tpl.php on line 34
```

My knowledge stopped here...

I've marked line `34` in the shorts function. I hope that the question is clear enough to understand, but I didn't really know how to describe it, since it's a pretty vague error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$content is the object.
$content->contents is an array.

So $content['contents'] won't work, because $content is an non-iterable object.
I don't know the structure of the Page class, but according to what you're saying, maybe this will work:

```
$content->contents['contents']
```

Comment: When I `var_dump` on `$content->contents` it returns": string(1736) "Some lorem ipsum", which would point out that `$content->contents`  isn't an array right?

Comment: The only arrays are in the `constructor` and in the `shorts` function, which are in the main post.

Comment: Can you execute a var_dump on $this->output too? Before line 34.

Comment: Returns `NULL`. I didn't define `$this->output` yet

Comment: The last thing I can think of is that $this->parameter is a multi-dimensional array => each value in array_values delivers also an array that triggers the notice. Can you var_dump $this->parameters? If this is not the case, I also ran out of options...